Stationary condition to a PDE problem
I am reading some papers about the properties of stationary solutions to a PDE problem. For example, let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb R^n$, then $u\in H^1(\Omega,\mathbb R)$ is a stationary solution means that for any vector field $Y\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}E(u\cdot +tY(\cdot))|_{t=0}=0
\end{equation*}
where $E(u)$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
E(u)=\int |\nabla u|^2.
\end{equation*}
If I have the above assumption, how could I obtain
\begin{equation*}
\int |\nabla u|^2\text{div}Y-DY(\nabla u,\nabla u)=0.
\end{equation*}
My thought: Since $u$ is only $H^1$, so I can't compute that directly, and I tried to use the Area formula or the chain rule of Frechet derivative, but I haven't obtain the conclusion yet.
I would be appreciate if someone can give me some hint for this problem.

What is the actual problem?

Sorry, I edit my problem again

What does u being in H^1 have to do with not being able to compute it?

Since $u\in H^1$, I think that $\partial_t \nabla u(x+tY)$ can not be defined correctly, and $\nabla u\cdot\nabla (\nabla u\cdot Y)$ also not exists.

Or I may ignore something, cause each paper I saw said that this can be obtained easily.
